# How to count number of times specific word occurs in a range in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, count, formula, spreadsheet, find-occurrences

I am analyzing data having 450000 cells in a column range which is taking a long time to find occurrences of a specific word hence hanging Excel. The formula I am using is `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,word,"")))/LEN(word)`

Please help me on this query.

Comment: It's an array formula on a lot of data so do expect it to take a long time. What did you use a the range-reference? Also, would the word always only occur just once in a cell?

Comment: [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)?

Comment: @ashleedawg No, you can also use wildcards (`?` and `*`) with countif. But if the respective word appears more than once in the cell, it will be only counted as 1 ...

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes, it counts *cells*  meeting a certain criterion. But as the question is quite vague, nobody knows, whether that will be enough or not ...

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be any faster (rather than using `SUMPRODUCT`, which is [known](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+sumproduct+slow) for it's poor performance):  `=SUM((LEN(A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,word,"")))/LEN(word))` to count occurrences of `word` in range `A:A`. (This is an array formula so hold CTRL while hitting Enter.)

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't see how that could possibly be faster. You're referencing all 1048576 cells in column A. I assume `range` is set to be more efficient than that.

Comment: @JosWoolley - as an [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), it will only check populated cells. I haven't tested performance but I bet it's faster than using `SUMPRODUCT`.  Further performance tips [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions) (including some specific to array formulas.)  ...([tag:VBA] would probably fastest by far, but the question isn't tagged that way)

Comment: @ashleedawg I have no idea where you heard that, but it's completely incorrect.

Comment: @JosWoolley - try it.

Comment: Close all workbooks, open a new workbook and paste your formula into a range of, say, 500 cells, e.g. `B1:U25`. Now watch Excel churn away for several minutes. You really should not post such misinformation: array formulas do not "check populated cells" only.